# Firefox extension debugging at startup

Tags: debugging, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events

I'm trying to debug code that is executed during extension startup ("load" event listener). When logging is not enough, is there a way to insert a breakpoint before extension loads?

I'm using native Browser Toolbox debugger. Load event of the extension is invoked only once at the browser startup as well and I can't find a way to insert a breakpoint before load handler finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the addon [Tiny JavaScript Debugger](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tiny-javascript-debugger/)

Comment: Probably use observer service and use 'xpcom-startup' observer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications